# How to loop through selected items in yaml sequence using haml

Tags: ruby, yaml, haml

I have a yaml sequence containing testimonials that I would like to loop through in full in some places but only partially in others. Briefly, how does one select and loop through specific items in a yaml sequence in haml?

*Examples below are stripped back*

**My yaml data**

```
# testimonials.yml

-
  name: 'Jill'
  quote: 'An unbelievable experience!'
  photo: 'jill.jpg'
-
  name: 'Jack'
  quote: 'I unreservedly recommend this programme'
  photo: 'jack.jpg'
-
  # ... etc
```

**A basic working haml loop**

```
-# about.html.haml

- data.testimonials.each do |testimonial|
  %div
    %img{ :src => testimonial.photo }
    %p= testimonial.name
    %p= testimonial.quote
```

**What I'm trying to achieve**

In another section, however, I only want to loop through specific testimonials in the sequence, eg. `[0, 4, 7]`. In my naivety, I presumed this would be similar to selecting specific sequence items outside of a loop, eg. `%p= data.testimonials[0].name`, like so:

```
- data.testimonials[0, 4, 7].each do |testimonial|
  %div
    %img{ :src => testimonial.photo }
    %p= testimonial.name
    %p= testimonial.quote
```

However... this returns a *'wrong number of arguments'* error, as it appears this method only accepts a single range within the sequence/ array, eg `testimonials[4, 7]` (or `[4..7]`, `2..2` etc).

**Question**

Is there a way to pass multiple ranges into this loop, eg. `[0..2 && 4..7]` (this doesn't work, but you get my drift)? Or, is this even the recommended way to achieve this outcome? That is, is there a standard and more efficient method for selecting and looping through specific items (or ranges of) in a yaml sequence?

<s>**Note**</s>

I feel the `select` method [in this post](http://jeromedalbert.com/ruby-how-to-iterate-the-right-way/) (pasted below) contains the answer... but I may be wrong, and I have no idea how to use it...

> **select**
>   *(alias to avoid: find_all)*
>   Very useful when you need to filter (i.e. “select”) multiple values.
>   `[1, 2, 3, 4].select { |e| e % 2 == 0 } # returns [2, 4]`

To test, I've tried to translate the above to `- data.testimonials.select do |testimonial| testimonial == 1`, which simply returns the entire sequence, as well as `- data.testimonial.select {|testimonial| testimonial == 1}`, which returns a syntax error...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use this [Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at)

eg.

```
- data.testimonials.values_at(0, 4, 7).each do |testimonial|
  %div
    %img{ :src => "#{testimonial.photo}" }
    %p= testimonial.name
    %p= testimonial.quote
```

Comment: This works too. I haven't come across `values_at`. Is this just an alternative to the two answers above or beneficial in some way? I can see it corresponds only to 'integer indices or ranges', which seem suited to yaml sequence items given they're just that

Comment: @eagobe benefit of  `values_at` is you will get array of given index only so that you dont need to loop through all the items of array,  whereas in other answers the whole array will get loop through and it will check the given condition for each and every element.

Answer (score 2):

use **[each_with_index](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index)**

```
- data.testimonials.each_with_index do |testimonial, index|
  - if [0, 4, 7].include? index
    %div
      %img{ :src => testimonial.photo }
      %p= testimonial.name
      %p= testimonial.quote
```

**OR**

You can use **[Array#values_at](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-values_at)** which will extract value of given index number and loop for those values only instead loop through all elements. 
for eg:

```
> array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"] 
> array.values_at(0, 4, 7)
#=> ["a", "e", "h"]
```

Comment: Excellent. Works perfectly

Comment: @eagobe : glad to help

Answer (score 1):

use each_with_index which will pass the element and its index,  then in the block do an if [2, 6, 9].include? index to check